# what connector/cable for 22pins connection

Tags: pcb, connector

In one of my project, I want to connect 2 PCB. I need to be able to have 22 wires minimum between the 2. on those lines, 19 are meant for +3.3V signals, 1 for a +5V power line, 1 for a +3.3V power line and 1 ground

I'm looking for a small connector with easily buyable cable or connector but the big number of pin make it hard to find what I need.

I thought about using multiple micro USB3 or micro USB2 sockets to connect all but it would need at least 3 which meen 3 separate cables.

I also throught about using IDE connector as IDE wire are widly available but they are a bit wide to my taste.

TL;DR :

- I'm looking for a connection to connect 2 PCB board
- With at least 22 pins
- For a small distance (10-20 cm)
- Somewhat uplugable (I may plug/unplug those a few times a year)

Comment: FYI, asking for recommendations for specific products is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Specific products, yes, but I think asking for general classes of solution is OK.

Comment: @pericynthion It seems he already has an idea of the "general class of solutions" he wants. He's asking for more specific recommendations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For board-to-board connections, I'd probably use ribbon cable and IDC connectors, mating with standard post headers on the boards.

Comment: Good recommendation. If the old bog standard headers with 0.1" spacing lead to too wide of cable the OP can consider headers and connectors with 2mm or 1.27mm lead spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I actually am working on a project at work with very similar requirements. I have selected some ready-made ribbon cables from Samtec ([FFSD series](https://www.samtec.com/products/ffsd)) that mate with the [ESHF series](https://www.samtec.com/products/eshf) board receptacle.

You can also find other standard IDC connectors on distributor websites like Digikey and Mouser, and separate ribbon cable. You can then cut the ribbon cable to the length you need and attach the connectors. Digikey also offers to make a cable for you, if that is your preference. I'm not sure if Mouser has the same service or not.

Comment: Good recommendation. I would only add that 1pin for ground for 19 signals and two power rails is very, softly speaking, too few. I would add at least three more grounds.

Comment: @AliChen It highly depends on the current the power rails will be carrying and the desired inductance. In most cases I would agree, I'd want at least as many grounds as power connections. More connections minimize inductance and resistance, but in many applications this may not be all that important. It's really only critical for high-speed projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very good question for this board.

I suggest a [DB25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) connector, the old serial connector on the IBM PC.

They can be used for all sorts of configurations and you get male and female in PCB (through hole and SMD, straight and right angle) and wire termination (solder and crimp)